# GAS: Create calendar event from spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I've the following columns in a spreadsheet:

| Email | Vorname | Name | Position | Thema | 19.02.23 | 22.02.23 | 28.02.23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a.b@gmail.com | Diego | Flores | AB | C | 1 |  |  |
| b.c@gmail.com | Alex | Flores | DB | F |  | 1 |  |
| c.d@gmail.com | Diego | Sanchez | GB | D | 1 |  |  |
| d.e@gmail.com | Alex | Sanchez | FB | G |  |  | 1 |

The spreadsheet is linked with the following google apps script:

```
function createCalendarEvents() {
  var spreadsheetId = '1NQULPeaxoaAaNWU4ojapb4R50JEdl62Ip2e9yjUB_sw';
  var calendarId = "diego.flores@gmail.com";
  var sheetName = '2';

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.shift();
  // console.log("spreadsheet: "+spreadsheet);
  // console.log("sheet: "+sheet);
  // console.log("calendar: "+calendar);
  // console.log("headers: "+headers);
  // console.log("data: "+data);
  console.log("email: "+email);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[0];
    var firstName = row[1];
    var lastName = row[2];
    var position = row[3];
    var topic = row[4];
    console.log("email: "+email);
    for (var j = 5; j < row.length; j++) {
      if (row[j] === '1') {
        var date = new Date(headers[j]);
        var eventTitle = firstName + " " + lastName + " - " + position + " - " + topic;
        var event = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, date, date);
        event.setLocation("Office");
        event.addEmailReminder(15);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a column contains a 1 in the date columns, the script should create an event filled with infos from the row in the calender diego.flores@gmail.com. But something it is not working, no calendar entry is created. I'm 100% sure I have the authorization for the calendar and the script is connected to the right sheet. Calendar and Spreadsheet API is activated. Maybe someone can give me a hint or tips. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `But something it is not working`?

Comment: No calendar event is created by executing the script

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and script, I proposed a modification point. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reply and your script,

- I think that in your script, `if (row[j] === '1') {` should be `if (row[j] === 1) {` when `row[j]` is a number, or `if (row[j] == '1') {`.

  - I thought that the reason of your current issue of `No calendar event is created by executing the script` might be due to this.
- From your sample data, I'm not sure whether the date of `19.02.23`, `22.02.23`, and `28.02.23` in your header titles are the date object.

From the above situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (row[j] === '1') {
  var date = new Date(headers[j]);
  var eventTitle = firstName + " " + lastName + " - " + position + " - " + topic;
  var event = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, date, date);
  event.setLocation("Office");
  event.addEmailReminder(15);
}
```

#### To:

```
if (row[j] == "1") {
  var date = headers[j] instanceof Date ? headers[j] : Utilities.parseDate(headers[j], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd.MM.yy");
  var eventTitle = firstName + " " + lastName + " - " + position + " - " + topic;
  var event = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, date, date);
  event.setLocation("Office");
  event.addEmailReminder(15);
}
```

- If the date of `19.02.23`, `22.02.23`, and `28.02.23` in your header titles are the date object, `var date = headers[j];` can be used instead of `{var date = headers[j] instanceof Date ? headers[j] : Utilities.parseDate(headers[j], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd.MM.yyyy");`.

#### References:

- [Strict equality (===)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- [Equality (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)